# How do I show data in Textview for a 2 second (android Studio)?

Tags: java, android, datainputstream, timedelay

I want to show data in  Textview for 2 second time.So I recieved data from arduino that not have a delay between I use serialwrite.I use InputStream and DatainputStream for recieved data.It's still have a problem when data show in textview.It will chance to the next data suddenly.Is there any method for hold it for 2 sec and chance it to next ? I write code in android Studio .
.

```
private void receive(byte[] data) {
        InputStream is = null;
        DataInputStream dis = null;
        try {
            is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            dis = new DataInputStream(is);
            while (dis.available() > 0) {
                byte[] b = new byte[data.length];
                dis.read(b, 0, 8);
                 count++;
                String part = HexDump.dumpHexString(b).substring(HexDump.dumpHexString(b).indexOf("E7 0"), HexDump.dumpHexString(b).indexOf("0A"));

               
             if (part.contains("E7 01")) {
                   //receive_text2.setText((part));
                    show_text(receive_text2,part);


                }
                if (part.contains("E7 02")) {
                    receive_text3.setText(String.valueOf(1000*unsiged(b[5])+100*unsiged(b[6])));

                }
                if (part.contains("E7 03")) {
                    receive_text4.setText((part));

                }
                if (part.contains("E7 05")) {
                    receive_text5.setText((part));

                }
                receive_text6.setText(String.valueOf(count));

            }
                


            

        }catch (Exception e){
             receive_text2.append("");
             receive_text3.append("");
             receive_text4.append("");
             receive_text5.append("");
             receive_text6.append("");
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to post a delay of 2 seconds (2000 millisec) with a Handler each time you attempt to set the text value.

```
TextView textView = ...;
textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText("some text");
    }
}, 2000); // delay of 2 seconds before setting a text to textView
```

Comment: It's not work .The result is it delay for 2 sec and then show data after that.It 's not delay again.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the strings you want to display into an Arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

then do:

```
Runnable job = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!strings.isEmpty()) {
            textView.setText(strings.get(0));
            strings.remove(0);
            textView.postDelayed(this, 2000);
        } else {
            textView.removeCallbacks(this);
        }
    }
};

textView.postDelayed(job, 2000); // delay of 2 seconds before setting a text to textView
```